# remove style = "flex-wrap:wrap" from my code

Tags: javascript, html, css

In internet explorer when I am unchecking style = "flex-wrap:wrap", then everything is working fine, so I

want to remove style = "flex-wrap:wrap" from my code, how can I do that.

What I tried is that I did  but then also after unchecking style =

"flex-wrap:wrap" only everything is working fine.

How can I do in code so that without unchecking in inspect in IE it directly works fine.

Comment: Can you show us the parts of your code that contains this style?

Comment: Perhaps use floats as a fallback? flex attributes first then the floats after (float left) with display block or display inline block. Have you tried the 'ms-' vendor prefix for that flex attribute? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function removeProperty(){
  const sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
  sheet.cssRules[0].style.removeProperty('flex-wrap')
}
```

where styleSheets is a array of styles; cssRules is an array of rules, pick your;
I advise you to make a console.log () for the sheets and the rules, so as to identify which ones you need to modify.